# Is there a CSS or JS solution to stop bad word wrapping arround images on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, javascript, css, responsive-webdesign

I have a blog post [here](https://thanetcreative.authorbuzz.co.uk/2020/04/make-your-word-processor-work-harder/) which works fine on a larger screen but not so much on a smaller one.

As you can see from the screenshot below the paragraph breaks very poorly around the image. Given how little space there is to the left, I'd like to make the text get under the image and have the image go full width (might as well) but I don't want to impact the desktop and big screen view.

[image]

I understand the basics of responsive design but I'm a bit lost on this particular issue. It is on a WordPress blog but I'm comfortable enough making a custom child theme to create changes. I'm just not sure what to change.

Comment: Hi Matthew, do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a css thing.

One solution is to use a css `@media (min-width: XXXpx)` query to disable wrapping if the screen width is small (e.g. set `float: none` on your `figure` element containing the image).

Comment: Agreed - definitely a case for using a `@media` query to remove the float and replace with something like: `margin: 12px auto;`.